# Error while routing the the page error code:Error: ENOENT, stat '/public/index.html' using node

Tags: node.js, express, ember.js, path

I use This code :

```
var express = require("express");
var path =  require("path");
var app =  express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use("/",function(req,res){
    res.sendfile('/public/index.html');
  //res.send("test");
}),
app.listen(5401)
```

**It working fine when I Enter url On Browser. shown in pic.**

[image]

**but in terminal i always getting en error :ENOENT, stat '/public/index.html'**
I don't know what is my mistake and i am using emberjs on client side

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
var express = require("express");
var path =  require("path");
var app =  express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use("/",function(req,res){
    res.sendfile(path.join(__dirname, '../public', 'index.html'));
  //res.send("test");
}),
app.listen(5401);
```

Comment: This actually helped me,I guess serving static files means that the file paths have to be changed a bit